# Is there any way to reset projects selected to run in Visual Studio "Multiple startup projects"?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

When working in a Visual Studio solution with many projects (e.g. around 100), is there any way of wiping all of the selected projects for "[Multiple startup projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-set-multiple-startup-projects?view=vs-2022)" instead of deselecting them one by one.

In other words, how do I set the action on all projects back to "None":

[image]

Comment: We use the [Switch Startup Project extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-141975.SwitchStartupProjectForVS2022)

Comment: Have you tried changing it to "Single Startup project", applying, and changing it back?  Or looking at the solution's JSON files to see if they can be edited?

Comment: @DStanley changing to "Single Startup project" and back preserves the selections and rightly so as you may want to temporarily run one project and then go back to your selection.

Comment: @stuartd prefer an in-built solution that doesn't require extensions but thanks - this will help if there is no better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like [Switch Startup Project extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-141975.SwitchStartupProjectForVS2022) (mentioned by
stuartd) is the only current solution to this.